# How to set global variable in vue.js so that it can be accessed from all components?

Tags: vuejs2

I need to use a global variable in vue.js which can be accessed across all components and can be changed from all components. I would prefer to initialise in in main.js. How can I initialise it and how to use it in another component?

Answer (score 0):

check this out [Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex) which is a Centralized State Management for Vue.js

Comment: If I created a store in main.js, how should I use it in my components? Using this.$store.state.count in another component is giving error

Comment: did you check the examples posted [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/counter) ?